# Optional parameter nullable

Tags: x++

Context:
In Ax, I'm exposing a webservice. The method takes 3 parameters. Two of them should be `Nullable<>` but I fail to do that in X++.

In c# the code would look like:

```
private static void FooBar(string[] things, DateTime? d1, DateTime? d2)
{
    if (d1 == null || d2 == null)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
    else {
        //Something Else
    }
}
```

How could I translate this? How can I build  a method with build optional, nullable parameters?

With Method overload [not suported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/overriding-a-method#overriding-vs-overloading) in X++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should translate to the following:

```
private static void FooBar(str things[], utcdatetime d1 = DateTimeUtil::minValue(), utcdatetime d2 = DateTimeUtil::minValue())
{
    if(d1!=DateTimeUtil::minValue()||d2!=DateTimeUtil::minValue())
    {
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
        //something else
    }
}
```

`things` is mandatory, `d1` & `d2` are optional